# How to deploy Angular 2 Quick Start project on Linux (CentOs)

Tags: linux, angular, npm, centos7, pm2

I don't understand how to deploy [this](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) on CentOS in daemon thread.
I can only start it with: `npm start`. But I want auto start it without my "intervention"!
Thank You!

*I try to do [this](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-serve-with-PM2), but it doesn't work. pm2 show server work fine, but i cannot see it in browser.*

```
│ status            │ online                          │
│ name              │ app                             │
│ restarts          │ 0                               │
│ uptime            │ 12h                             │
│ script path       │ /usr/bin/http-server            │
│ script args       │ dist -p 3030                    │
│ error log path    │ /root/.pm2/logs/app-error-0.log │
│ out log path      │ /root/.pm2/logs/app-out-0.log   │
│ pid path          │ /root/.pm2/pids/app-0.pid       │
│ interpreter       │ node                            │
│ interpreter args  │ N/A                             │
│ script id         │ 0                               │
│ exec cwd          │ /usr/share/soeui                │
│ exec mode         │ fork_mode                       │
│ node.js version   │ 6.9.1                           │
│ watch & reload    │ ✘                               │
│ unstable restarts │ 0                               │
│ created at        │ 2016-12-21T20:52:58.239Z        |
```

UPDATE
Summary, I just need another servel like nginx for example to deploy it.

Comment: i am a bit confused.. you want to code angular2 using this quickstart template.. or see the final result after you built it ?

Comment: I just want to see, how can I deploy it if I write my own code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the best way is to use angular-cli(https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

- create a new local folder on your own computer
- pull the git project into the folder
- run 'npm install' on your local machine
- run 'ng build' on your local machine
- copy the /dist folder from your local folder to your centOS webserver(apache2 or something)

i am not sure if this is what you expect, but this is how i would do it :)

Comment: I did like you say and what next? :) I don't know how to start it :) My decision do same result

Comment: Ok, I see, I just need another server to deploy it.

Comment: How can we serve angular project ? 
Do we need to  ng serve running in background on server  ?

Comment: no.. ng serve ist just for testing.. with ng build you create a javascript bundle which u just have to move to your apache folder on the server.